# Julia function argument type def

Tags: function, arguments, parameter-passing, julia

I faced some problem regarding defining the type of arguments for a function in Julia. 
From one hand, the code would be faster to run if the type is defined: for example Int64 for an integer number. On the other hand, passing a simple number to the function would needs type cast every time I call the function, e.g. by calling:

```
convert(a, Int64)
```

That seems to be an overkill. 
what is the advice for good style?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Julia, it's not generally true that specifying the type for a function's argument(s) will make it faster.  If the argument has no type (i.e. `Any`), or has just an abstract type (for example, `Integer` instead of `Int64`, Julia can generate methods for whatever concrete types are actually used to call the function, instead of having to do any conversion.
BTW, the syntax is actually `convert(Int64, a)`, the type you wish to convert to comes first.